# What's a phrase for "doing what you know" even when it's wrong?

Tags: expressions

We see several tropes over on the DIY forum.  People have problem A, but **they don't know how to fix problem A**, so they fix problem B that isn't broken *solely because they know how to do that*.

Typically, it is perfectly obvious that the problem is A not B, or only a moment's thought or an easy test would tell them that, but their skill at B pulls them like a magnet to that "solution".

For instance

- A water heater has a bad element that costs $12.  It trips the correct 30-amp circuit breaker, so they change the breaker to a 40A ($11).  Later, that trips, *so clearly something is wrong*.  But they change it to a 60A ($11) etc. etc.  *They know how to change breakers. They don't know how to change elements*.
- A $15 coffee grinder has a ground fault.  This trips their ground fault detector (GFCI/RCD).  *They could go plug it into the (different) GFCI in the bathroom*, but no -- they instantly ***presume the detector is faulty*** and spend $20 changing it (the US style is easy to change).

My first thought was "rearranging deck chairs on the *Titanic*" but that seems to be about a tragically pointless effort done out of lack of awareness.

What's a better phrase for that?

Comment: Related (or a duplicate?) - [What does “proverbial man with a hammer” mean in this context?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/35897/what-does-proverbial-man-with-a-hammer-mean-in-this-context) That's to say if all you've got is a hammer, you just hammer everything as you would a nail. By the same token, if all you know how to do is change fuses, that's the only way you could try to fix any electrical problem.

Comment: also relevant: ["Whatever a Russiab does they end up making the Kalashnikov](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/496021/whatever-a-russian-does-they-end-up-making-the-kalashnikov-gun-are-there-any)

Comment: Is this related to the "[XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)"?